# Table form for django site

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

My first stackoverflow question so i hope you'll be nice :P.

I am trying to learn django and use bootstrap for a university project in a subject that teaches group collaboration methodology and no coding.
So we are on our own to learn the languages and frameworks we choose.

My problem is:
How do i get a nice table for my  list such as the one on bootstraps webpage: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

my .html file for the list looks as following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Users</h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
    {% for user in object_list %}
      <li class="contact">{{ user }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<a href="{% url "users:user_new" %}">Add User</a>
{% endblock %}
```

but it still just shows as a normal html  list with no bootstrap styling :S
I may have completely missed out on something essential so i hope you can help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting table styling because `<li>` elements can't be part of table. Use `<tr>` and `<td>` elements instead to build your table.

Example:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    {% for user in object_list %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ user }}</td>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks a lot. Have never done any web before, so after a quick search your answer makes perfect sense! My HTML knowledge is just non-existing :D
Say a user consists of first_name, last_name and email, how do i divide them using <tr> <td> tags?